# Http запрос javascript

Tags: javascript, http

Только что задавал подобные вопрос, наверное я не правильно выразился, или меня не правильно поняли.

Нужно сделать `http` запрос, сайту и получить ответ

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "http://ya.ru/index.html", true);
x.onreadystatechange = function () {
alert(x.responseText);
}
x.send(null);
</script>
```

Я хочу, чтобы алерт вывел мне html код главной страницы яндекса.

Например: на php можно сделать так:

```
$html = get_file_contents("http://ya.ru/index.html");
```

или

```
$html = "";
$sock = fsockopen ("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if ($sock ) {
fputs ($sock , "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: ya.ru\r\n\r\n");
while (!feof($sock))
$html .= fgets($sock , 1024);
} 
fclose ($sock);
}
```

Т.е. в переменной `html` у нас содержится `html` код страницы сайта, куда был выполнен запрос.

Тоже самое нужно сделать на `javascript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Средствами браузера это можно сделать только в том случае, если на удаленном сервере включена поддержка [CORS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Обойти это можно например используя proxy (http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/42ecy/ ):

```
loadURL('http://ya.ru', function (html){
    alert(html);
});

function loadURL(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", 'http://jsonp.jit.su/?url=' + decodeURIComponent(url), true);
    xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function () {
        var html = xhr.responseText;
        try {
            // логика работы с конкретной проксей
            html = JSON.parse(code);
            html = html.success || html.error;
        } catch (er) {}
        callback(html);
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}
```